# Nicer way to typeset multidimensional integrals

Tags: formatting

I am writing a multidimensional integral as follows :

[image: here]

Is there any way I can make the $\int d^{D}x$ part appear nicer? Preferably, by moving x towards the part with $\int d^{D}$

I am using the math-font `Garamond-Math` and regular-font `EB Garamond` with package `unicode-math` and compiling using `XeLaTeX`.

Edit : My LaTeX Code :

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm} %for boldface math
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[a4paper, scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={6,10}]

\begin{document}
\[
\int d^{D}x \left( - \frac{1}{2} \partial _{\mu} \phi \partial ^{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^{2} \phi^{2} \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you mean with nicer? Just move the letter?

Comment: IMO, what you have is already nice!

Comment: Please show your LaTeX code.

Comment: @Eric This is already as close as `x` is willing to go towards `d^D`.

Comment: @Mico Edited the question with my code.

Comment: @Roboticist At this point it is just about OCD for perfection!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Note the use of `\tfrac` instead of `\frac`, `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of `\left` and `\right`, various positive and negative whitespace adjustments, and  @Schrödinger'scat's suggestion to typeset the differential operator using an upright `d` glyph. (Aside, in case you're not familiar with `\mkern`: `\,` ("positive thinspace") corresponds to `\mkern3mu`, and `\!` ("negative thinspace") corresponds to `\mkern-3mu`; `1em=18mu`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}[StylisticSet={6,10}]
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this exercise
\begin{document}
Original form:
\[
\int d^{D}x \left( - \frac{1}{2} \partial _{\mu} \phi \partial ^{\mu} \phi 
     - \frac{1}{2} m^{2} \phi^{2} \right)
\]

Suggested alternative:
\[
\int \mkern-5mu \diff^{D}\!x \,\bigl(-\tfrac{1}{2} \partial_{\mkern-2mu\mu} \phi\,
 \partial^{\mkern1mu\mu}\!\phi -\tfrac{1}{2} m^2\mkern-1.5mu\phi^2\bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that in physics `d` usually denotes the number of (extra) spacetime dimensions, which is yet another reason why it is a good practice to typeset differential `di`s upright.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat So do I just use : `\int \mkern-5mu \text{d}^{D}\!x` i.e. just put `d` in text environment? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Mico This is simply awesome. I found out a lot of new things here. Thanks. :)

Comment: Mico and @Nitin You can use `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`. Anyway, typeset differential d's upright.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - I've updated my answer to incorporate your suggestion.